# Eexpected operational time of a priority queue

Tags: java

Just need to know, what is the expected operational time of a priority queue

O(n) O(lg n) or O(2) or O(1) or O(3)

Comment: @Thilo over all, i mean for all operations

Comment: O(2) and O(3) doesn't make sense. Big O notation will remove any constant in the formula to calculate the complexity, so they are the same as O(1). If the constant matter, then you should not use Big-O notation (at least for the highest term).

Answer (score 4):

Then read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for
>   the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add);
>   linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and
>   constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).

Comment: Bummer. Now he has to check all three of his options: O(log n), O(n), O(1)

Comment: Priority queue. It needs to keep some sort of structure in order to find the highest priority element.

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue has these main methods:

- add(e)/offer(e) - adds element e to queue: O(log(n))
- peek() - gets the first element of the sorted queue: O(1)
- pool() - gets the first element of the sorted queue and removes it from the queue: O(log(n))
- remove(e) - removes element e from the list O(log(n))
- contains - checks if queue contains element e: O(n)

where n represents the number of elements from the queue.